# Multiple nested matches in JavaScript Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to write a regular expression to match GS1 barcode patterns ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GS1-128 ), that contain 2 or more of these patterns that have an identifier followed by a certain number of characters of data.

I need something that **matches** this barcode because it contains 2 of the identifier and data patterns:

human readable with the identifiers in parens: (01)12345678901234(17)501200

actual data: `011234567890123417501200`

but **should match not** this barcode when there is only one pattern in:

human readable: (01)12345678901234

actual data: `0112345678901234`

It seems like the following should work:

```js
var regex = /(?:01(\d{14})|10([^\x1D]{6,20})|11(\d{6})|17(\d{6})){2,}/g;
var str = "011234567890123417501200";

console.log(str.replace(regex, "$4"));
// matches 501200
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$1"));
// no match? why?
```

For some strange reason as soon as I remove the `{2,}` it works, but I need the `{2,}` so that it only returns matches if there is more than one match.

```js
// Remove {2,} and it will return the first match
var regex = /(?:01(\d{14})|10([^\x1D]{6,20})|11(\d{6})|17(\d{6}))/g;
var str = "011234567890123417501200";

console.log(str.replace(regex, "$4"));
// matches 501200
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$1"));
// matches 12345678901234
// but then the problem is it would also match single identifiers such as
var str2 = "0112345678901234";
console.log(str2.replace(regex, "$1"));
```

How do I make this work so it will only match and pull the data if there is more than 1 set of match groups?

Thanks!

Comment: What is expected match?

Comment: I've modified the question to illustrate what the matches are. Thanks!

Comment: Is `011234567890123417501200` string or number? Are `01` and `17` constants?

Comment: 011234567890123417501200 is a string returned from the barcode scanner and 01 and 17 are identifiers, as seen in the GS1-128 spec, that indicate what what the type of data will be and the number of characters it will contain.

Comment: Have you tried creating an object where property names are code sequence and values the `.length` of string that is expected adjacent to AI? Then checking string for pairs of key, value pairs?

Comment: Not sure I follow... are you saying to not use RegEx? I need to use RegEx because it comes from a configuration setting that is different per client in our database.

Comment: `var matches = {"01":/01(?=\d{14})/, "17":/17(?=\d{6})/}`, match each property, value or return `false`. You could also use a function and `.every()` which returns `true` or `false` to pass `[matches]`, iterating property and value to create  `RegExp()` from parameters passed. Can you describe specific pattern? What are OR parts of `RegExp`?

Comment: That is, break the `RegExp` into portions where you are certain the correct `Boolean` is returned, instead of trying to use a single `RegExp` `var fn = function (str, re) {
  return re.every(function(regex) {
           return regex.test(str)
  })
}; fn(str, [/01(?=\d{14})/, /17(?=\d{6})/])`

Comment: Yes, thats what I was trying to do in the last part of my updated post, where I mention that everything works correctly if I just remove the `{2,}` , but I'm trying to figure out why. It seems that it is recognizing that there are two matches, since it will return the second match (the $4), but for some reason it is recognizing the fact that it has two matches, but it won't return the first of the two matches.

Comment: Is issue `:`? Reviewing `RegExp`, is there actually only a single capture group? You can get matches one at a time using `.match()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your RegEx is logically and syntatically correct for Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE).  The issue I believe you are facing is the fact that JavaScript has issues with repeated capture groups.  This is why the RegEx works fine once you take out the `{2,}`.  By adding the quantifier, JavaScript will be sure to return **only** the last match.

What I would recommend is removing the `{2,}` quantifier and then programmatically checking for matches.  I know it's not ideal for those who are big fans of RegEx, but *c'est la vie*.

Please see the snippet below:

```js
var regex = /(?:01(\d{14})|10([^\x1D]{6,20})|11(\d{6})|17(\d{6}))/g;
var str = "011234567890123417501200";

// Check to see if we have at least 2 matches.
var m = str.match(regex);
console.log("Matches list: " + JSON.stringify(m));
if (m.length < 2) {
    console.log("We only received " + m.length + " matches.");
} else {
    console.log("We received " + m.length + " matches.");
    console.log("We have achieved the minimum!");
}

// If we exec the regex, what would we get?
console.log("** Method 1 **");
var n;
while (n = regex.exec(str)) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(n));
}

// That's not going to work.  Let's try using a second regex.
console.log("** Method 2 **");
var regex2 = /^(\d{2})(\d{6,})$/;
var arr = [];
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0, len = m.length; i < len; i++) {
    arr = m[i].match(regex2);
    obj[arr[1]] = arr[2];
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

// EOF
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it is a JavaScript specific issue! That's the what I was hoping not to be the case, but the only one that made sense to me having seen that it worked correctly in Ruby, with the online Ruby RegEx utility: http://www.rubular.com/

Do you know anywhere that documents the "issues with repeated capture groups" in JavaScript?

Comment: I don't know of any place that explicitly states that the JavaScript RegEx engine doesn't do this properly; however, different languages do have different reputations with their respect to regular expressions.  JS's reputation is not so good.  I did find this page (http://www.rexegg.com/regex-javascript.html#crippled) which explains some of the common issues JS has with RegEx as well as proposes a library that may be of use.

Comment: @Grisza Nice! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the capture groups only give the last match by that particular group. Imagine that you would have two barcodes in your sequence that have both the same identifier `01`... now it becomes clear that `$1` cannot refer to both at the same time. The capture group only retains the second occurrence.

A straightforward way, but not so elegant, is to drop the `{2,}`, and instead repeat the whole regular expression pattern for matching the second barcode sequence. I think you also need to use the `^` (start of string anchor) to be sure the match is at the start of the string, otherwise you might pick up an identifier halfway an invalid sequence. After the repeated regular expression pattern you should also add `.*` if you want to ignore anything that follows after the second sequence, and not have it come back to you when using `replace`.

Finally, as you don't know which identifier will be found for the first and second match, you need to reproduce `$1$2$3$4` in your `replace`, knowing that only one of those four will be a non-empty string. Same for the second match: `$5$6$7$8`.

Here is the improved code applied to your example string:

```js
var regex = /^(?:01(\d{14})|10([^\x1D]{6,20})|11(\d{6})|17(\d{6}))(?:01(\d{14})|10([^\x1D]{6,20})|11(\d{6})|17(\d{6})).*/;

var str = "011234567890123417501200";
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$1$2$3$4")); // 12345678901234
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$5$6$7$8")); // 501200
```

If you need to also match the barcodes that follow the second, then you cannot escape from writing a loop. You cannot do that with just a regular expression based `replace`.

#### With a loop

If a loop is allowed, then you can use the `regex#exec` method. I would then suggest to add in your regular expression a kind of "catch all", which will match one character if none of the other identifiers match. If in the loop you detect such a "catch all" match, you exit:

```js
var str = "011234567890123417501200";
var regex = /(?:01(\d{14})|10([^\x1D]{6,20})|11(\d{6})|17(\d{6})|(.))/g;
//              1: ^^^^^^  2: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  3: ^^^^^  4: ^^^^^ 5:^ (=failure)
var result = [], grp;
while ((grp = regex.exec(str)) && !grp[5]) result.push(grp.slice(1).join(''));

// Consider it a failure when not at least 2 matched.
if (result.length < 2) result = [];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I like your thinking, but I just came up with another idea, based partially on your idea of duplicating the whole pattern twice, but instead, I made the second group a look ahead: `(?:01(\d{14})|10([^\x1D]{6,20})|11(\d{6})|17(\d{6}))(?=01(\d{14})|10([^\x1D]{6,20})|11(\d{6})|17(\d{6}))` and when done this way it seems to still return all the matches! Thanks for the answer, and inspiration!

Comment: But then the `replace` you used will give a result that will include more than just the match.

Comment: You're right, yeah, that seems to give more than what's needed for $1, though with $4 it works correctly... strange. Darn, so close! Thanks!

Comment: The main issue I see with your original solution is that it only works if there are two matches in the barcode, which works for my one given example, but in reality there can be more than 2 matches in a barcode, which is why I had used `{2,}` instead of `{2}`. Duplicating the pattern as many times as their might be matches seems excessive and hard to maintain. For that reason, I might favor another solution.

Comment: That is what I wrote near the end of my answer. If you need a dynamic number of matches, you need to loop. Is looping through the matches an acceptable solution for you? If so, I can provide that, it was just that I got the impression when you talked about RegEx configuration settings, your setup does not allow to work with anything else than a single regex -replace that does it all.

Comment: Anyway, I added a loop-based solution to my answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! But then how do you tell which match group the result is from?

Comment: The groups are in the `grp` array, starting from index 1, since at index 0 you find the complete match. Only one of the capture groups can be a non-empty string at one time, you can just skip the string at index 0 and join the others with `grp.slice(1).join('')`. If you want to test for individual group, do `if (grp(i) !== '') ...`.

Answer (score 0):

## update

**1st example**

example with $1 $2 $3 $4 don't know why in matrix :)

but you see $1 -> abc
$2 -> def $3 -> ghi $4 -> jkl

```js
//              $1   $2     $3  $4
var regex = /(abc)|(def)|(ghi)|(jkl)/g;
var str = "abcdefghijkl";

// test  
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$1 1st "));
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$2 2nd "));
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$3 3rd "));
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$4 4th "));
```

**2nd example**

sth in here is mixing faulty

```js
//              $1   $2     $3  $4
var regex = /((abc)|(def)|(ghi)|(jkl)){2,}/g;
var str = "abcdefghijkl";

// test  
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$1 1st "));
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$2 2nd "));
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$3 3rd "));
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$4 4th "));
```

As you see there is `($4)( )( )( )` instead of `($1)( )( )( )`.

If I think correctly the problem is with outside brackets `()` confusing 'pseudo' $1 is $4. If you have in outside brackets `()` a pattern and then `{2,}` so in outside brackets `()` it is $4 but in subpattern there is  `(?:01(\d{14}))` but it reads like not $1 but faulty in this case $4 . Maybe this cause conflicts between the remembered values in outside brackets ()  and 1st remembered values but inside brackets **(this is $1)** . That's why it doesn't display. In other words you have ($4 ($1 $2 $3 $4) ) and this is not correct.

I add the picture to show what I mean.

[image]

As @Damian said

> By adding the quantifier, JavaScript will be sure to return only the last match.

so $4 is the last match.

## end update

I added useful little test

```js
var regex = /(?:01(\d{14})|10(\x1D{6,20})|11(\d{6})|17(\d{6})){2,}/g;
var str = "011234567890123417501200";

// test
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$1 1st "));
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$2 2nd "));
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$3 3rd "));
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$4 4th "));
```

Comment: Thanks! But the `[^\x1D]` is to stop the data match if there is an invisible Group Separator character as seen here: http://condor.depaul.edu/sjost/lsp121/documents/ascii-npr.htm

How else would I negate that character?

Comment: In your latest example, the last console outputs: 1234567890123417501200 when it should only output 12345678901234

Comment: that's why I said seems works :) @JacobH to negate without [^ ] use `\X` it negates hex value

Comment: Looks like you updated it again. Thanks for investigating! It looks like it's back to the original problem though, in that it won't return any of the matches except for the last match.

Comment: You would make your text more readable if you would finish sentences once in a while.

Comment: *"a backslash \ and escaped in negated area don't have meaning"*: that is not true: the backslash does have a meaning in negated classes.